# Prove that $(a,c)\cdot (a,d)=a\cdot(a,(b,(c,d)))$ if $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $ab=cd$

Tags: number-theory

Use the property $(ab,ac)=a\cdot (b,c)$ - the greatest common factor feature

Then $a\cdot(a,(b,(c,d))) = (a^2,a\cdot(b,(c,d))) = (a^2,(ab,a\cdot(c,d))) = (a^2,(ab,(ac,ad))) = (a^2,(cd,(ac,ad)))$

Is this correct? How to get $(a,c)\cdot (a,d)$?

I got!! There is the right solution:

We know that $(ab,ac)=a\cdot (b,c)$ and we know gcd's associativity and commutativity.

Then $a(a,(b,(c,d))) = (a^2,a(b,(c,d))) = (a^2,(ab,a(c,d))) = (a^2,(ab,(ac,ad))) = (a^2,(cd,(ac,ad))) = (a^2,(cd,(ad,ac))) = (a^2,((cd,ad),ac)) = (a^2,(d(c,a),ac)) =  (a^2,(ac,d(c,a))) = ((a^2,ac),d(c,a)) = (a(a,c),d(a,c)) = (a,c)\cdot (a,d)$

Thank You.

Comment: Do you really mean cot (as in cotangent)?

Comment: Can you put the question into the main body as well? Also there is no $b$ on the left hand side of the equation. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There is \cdot @Lord Shark the Unknown

Comment: @PeterPatzt This is correct.

Comment: This is not clear at all.  Please work a numerical example.  Say $a=3,b=4, c=6, d=2$.  Then we have $ab=cd$.  Can you explain what calculation you perform to check your claim in this case?

Comment: If you reduce the computation to a single prime and let $x,y,z,w$ be the multiplicity of that prime in $a,b,c,d$, respectively, then the equation reduces to $min(x,z)+min(x,w) = x + min(x,y,z,w)$ for $x+y=z+w$. This can be easily proved by a case study. (There might be a nicer proof for the last equation.)

Comment: @lulu I have to prove $(a,c)\cdot (a,d)=a\cdot(a,(b,(c,d)))$, where $(a,c)$, $(a,d)$, .... are the greatest common factor

Comment: I got a solution and edit my post. Thanks for helping :)